# Frequent Cache misses for loading data and accumulating Elements of std vector

Tags: c++, perf, performancecounter

Perf reports that a simple app, which loads a binary blob from the disk and accumulates its elements, has ~3E+07  cache misses. The program is shown below:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

std::vector<float> read_blob(const std::string& file_path, int sz) {
    std::vector<float> data(sz);
    std::fstream file(file_path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        throw std::runtime_error{"Cannot open buffer from disk"};
    }
    file.read((char*)data.data(), sizeof(float) * sz);
    file.close();
    return data;
}

int main() {
    constexpr size_t sz{311040000};
    const std::string path{"/tmp/blob.bin"};
    std::vector<float> data = read_blob(path, sz);
    float sum =
        std::accumulate(data.begin(), data.end(), 0.0F) / (float)data.size();
    std::cout << "the sum is " << sum << std::endl;
}
```

The program is compiled with `-O3` optimization for my machine `-march=native`. Digging further, I see that the majority of the misses occur before `main` and are associated with a `brnf_frag_data_storage ([br_netfilter])` . In more detail:

|  | Cache Misses |
| --- | --- |
| brnf_frag_data_storage ([br_netfilter]) | 2.058E+07 (60%) |
| Main | 1.325E+07 (40%) |
| Total | 3.838E+07 |

My questions are:

- What is happening before `main` is called?
- Can I somehow ask perf to consider only events starting with main?
- Given the length of the vector, I seem to have a cache miss for every ~31 elements. How can they be so frequent?

Comment: "What happens before `main` is called" - A lot: https://youtu.be/dOfucXtyEsU

Comment: Watching a video of Matt Godbolt is always nice - thanks, @MarekR.

Comment: I imagine this program spends most of the time in `file.read` call. Which could be where most of the cache misses occur. Though it likely doesn't matter there, as the call is likely I/O-bound rather than CPU-bound.

Comment: Are you sure your list is ordered by time?  It could just be sorted with the most cache-misses first.  That could be some iostream code called from `file.read`.

Comment: Or actually that could be kernel code.  Was your machine handling a lot of network packets while this was running?  `brnf_frag_data_storage` is in Linux's firewalling ethernet bridge code: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/bridge/br_netfilter_hooks.c  . If you just want to profile your own code, use `perf stat --all-user` if you don't care what happens inside system-calls.  (This could distort things if you're comparing `read` vs. `mmap`, since with `read` more work happens inside the kernel.)

Comment: A `float` is 4 bytes, a cache line is 64 bytes (on modern x86, which I assume you're using since you didn't specify otherwise...)  Hardware prefetch can often avoid some cache misses, otherwise you'd expect one per cache line (one per 16 floats).  Multiple misses to the same line might result in multiple counts for `L1-dcache-load-misses` but only one access to outer caches as all the loads attach themselves to the same buffer that's waiting for the incoming cache line.